# Is it possible to functionally traverse objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, object

I think JavaScript doesn't have anything like *obj.first*, but I was wondering if something like this can be achieved in any way:

```
var foobar = { aint: "foo", an: "bar", array: "foobar" };
var recursiveObjDump = function (obj, idx) {
    if (idx == obj.last.index) return obj[idx];
    else return obj[idx] + " " + recursiveObjDump(obj, obj[idx].next.index);
};

alert( recursiveObjDump(foobar, foobar.first.index) );
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you just trying to inspect objects for debugging?  If so, just use Firebug.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. Objects in Javascript are associative arrays - sets of key/value pairs. There is no specified order, just as in a [mathematical set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) (compare to a [sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence)). Therefore, looking for something like `object.first` is meaningless.

On the other hand, you can absolutely impose your own structure on top of this. For instance, you could implement Lisp-style lists in Javascript, and recur over those. [This is a pretty neat article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-javascript.html) on using functional programming techniques in Javascript.

In the end, Javascript is object-oriented, not functional, so you're just not going to find those functional primitives implemented natively.

**Edit:** If you still want to use functional programming techniques in Javascript, have a look at [Functional Javascript](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for in` to loop through all the properties.

This is a basic one, you could add better detection to look for Arrays and such as well.

```
var foobar = { aint: "foo", an: "bar", array: "foobar" };

function recusiveDump(obj) {
    var output = '';
    for(var i in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            if(typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
                output += recusiveDump(obj[i]);
            } else {
                output += obj[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}

alert(recusiveDump(foobar));
```

Comment: The function `recursiveDump` calls itself; therefore it is recursive.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to serialize an object, use [JSON.stringify()](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js). It is native in Javascript 5, and you can download a script from Crockford's site for lower javascript versions. (the same script can reparse the JSON object serialization safely back to a javascript object again)